# Neo4j Large Data Rendering

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm working with a large data set that really warrants a graph db. My goal is to visualize identify trends in the data set to make decisions.

I'm currently using neo4j and i really like the tool, however the nodes returned are capped at 300. This number is only a fraction of my data, and doesnt really allow me to gain the insight i've been looking for, even with queries to filter out portions. Additionally, I'd really like to add node weights and color per conditions, which isn't possible using just neo4j.

Has anybody found a solution to this problem. I'd imagine there may be some client side libraries designed for these sorts of problems. Alternatively, I wouldn't be opposed to switching to some other graph db better suited to solve these problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Neo4j Bloom](https://neo4j.com/product/bloom/). This will provide you better visualization of your Neo4j data.